# Should we end stored procedures with the GO statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Should we end stored procedures with GO statement, if so what are the advantages of using GO?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetAddress @City nvarchar(30)
AS
SELECT * 
FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Address
WHERE City = @City
GO
```

Comment: `GO` is only a command for SSMS to execute the previous statement(s).  It is, by itself, not valid SQL.  It has zero impact on your stored procedure.

Comment: @Siyual then why many of the stored procedure example on the internet use GO

Comment: `GO` separates the statements into their own batches to be run individually.  `Create Procedure` can only be run if it's the only thing in the batch. So terminating the statement with `GO` before and after the `Create Procedure` will make sure that it can run.  But if it's your only statement, it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement `go`, [per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

> Signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL Server utilities.
>
> ...
>
> `GO` is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql
>   utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.
>
> SQL Server utilities interpret `GO` as a signal that they should send the current batch
>   of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL Server. The current batch of statements
>   is composed of all statements entered since the last `GO`, or since the start of the
>   ad-hoc session or script if this is the first `GO`.
>
> A Transact-SQL statement cannot occupy the same line as a `GO` command. However, the line
>   can contain comments.
>
> Users must follow the rules for batches. For example, any execution of a stored procedure
>   after the first statement in a batch must include the `EXECUTE` keyword. The scope of
>   local (user-defined) variables is limited to a batch, and cannot be referenced after a
>   `GO` command.

A stored procedure definition, [per the documentation for `create procedure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), comes with restrictions. it must be the first (and only) statement in the batch:

> The `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement cannot be combined with other Transact-SQL statements in
>   a single batch.

That means the body of stored procedure ends with the batch. Adding `GO` in your source file is good practice. Especially since it's common to do things prior to and following the creation of a stored procedure. You'll often see source files that look something like this:

```
if (object_id('dbo.foobar') is not null ) drop procedure dbo.foobar
GO
-- dbo.foobar --------------------------------------------
-- 
-- This stored procedure does amazing and wonderful things
----------------------------------------------------------
create procedure dbo.foobar
as

   ...
   {a sequence of amazing and wonderful SQL statements}
   ...
   return 0
GO

grant execute on dbo.foobar to some_schema
GO
```

And the value for `GO` is adjustable in Sql Server Management Studio's options. If you'd like to use something like `jump` instead of `go`, you can (bearing in mind that you're almost certainly going to give yourself grief in doing so.).

[image: options screenshot]

Comment: Could you please help also for this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127813/usage-of-as-statement-to-create-functions-in-sql-server

Comment: @osman: There's not much to "help" there. The Transact-SQL grammar makes `as` optional, (per the documentation for `create function`)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755(v=sql.110).aspx]. Use it, or don't use it: it makes no difference. My preference is to omit optional keywords, in general as, in my opinion, they clutter the source code and decreate the signal/noise ratio. So I say `left join` instead of `left outer join` and `join` instead of `inner join`.

Answer (score 4):

No, you should end your procedure with `RETURN`.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetAddress @City nvarchar(30)
 AS
   SELECT * 
   FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Address
   WHERE City = @City

 RETURN
```

The `GO` is really meant to separate commands in a sql script.

Comment: Is AS statement mandatory for both stored procedures and functions?

Comment: Why I should use return statement, can I use nothing?

Comment: all procedures technically return something, it's a good coding practice, but you don't have to do it.

Comment: One should terminate the stored procedure with and explicit `return 0` rather than depending on the default return code of zero (0).

Comment: When I start a new procedure in SSMS, the starting code template does not include the keyword return.  I see no reason to add it.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to point out that without a `GO` at the end of your stored procedure, any T-SQL after the supposed end of the procedure body will still be included in the body of the proc.

For example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Foo
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Bar;
END

DROP TABLE dbo.Bar;
```

In this example, running `EXEC dbo.Foo`  will end up dropping the table even though it is after the `END`.  To avoid that, you need to place a `GO` after the `END`.

Comment: This tripped me up greatly. I'm always going to use GO after creating a procedure now.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to surround the body of the stored procedure with `begin` and `end` statements:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetAddress (
    @City nvarchar(30)
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Address
    WHERE City = @City;
END;
```

`GO` is a not a T-SQL command.  It is understood by the tools that run scripts.  As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) describes:

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the
>   sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code
>   editor.
>
> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should send
>   the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL
>   Server. The current batch of statements is composed of all statements
>   entered since the last GO, or since the start of the ad hoc session or
>   script if this is the first GO.

By the way, in your case, a user-defined table function might be more appropriate than a stored procedure.

Comment: If you're having problems getting a stored procedure to compile, it is often useful in finding the error to compile it a chunk at a time, selecting everything from the `create procedure` down a statement at a time, gradually extending the selection until you've identified the problem. Enclosing the stored procedure body in a `begin`/`end` block precludes doing that.

Comment: @NicholasCarey . . . Not if you add an `end` instead of/in addition to a `go` when you want to test it.

Comment: With the body of a stored procedure enclosed in `begin`/`end`, If I select the first 50 lines of a 500 line stored procedure and press CTL+E to compile it, an immediate syntax error will result due to the unclosed begin. That sort of partial compilation technique is often useful, as I noted, in identifying the locus of a compile error: gradually extending the bounds of what gets compiled until the problem statement is identified.