# Usage of 'AS' statement to create functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures

Is it mandatory to use AS statement when creating functions. Almost every example including MSDN uses AS statement while creating function. From MSDN,

[image]

But actually I can create a function without using AS statement and it works.

[image]

So why we are using AS statement for creating functions, although it works without it?

The second question is that, I tried the same scenario for stored procedures and realized that it is mandatory to use AS statement. Is it true that, usage of AS is mandatory for creating stored procedure but not for creating functions.

Comment: The As, although not mandatory, is seen as good practice in UDFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax from the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) is

```sql
--Transact-SQL Scalar Function Syntax
CREATE FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name 
( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ][ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type 
    [ = default ] [ READONLY ] } 
    [ ,...n ]
  ]
)
RETURNS return_data_type
    [ WITH <function_option> [ ,...n ] ]
    [ AS ]
    BEGIN 
        function_body 
        RETURN scalar_expression
    END
[ ; ]
```

Notice that the use of `AS` is optional here. (See [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx))

And yes, `AS` is required when creating [stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx), but not when creating functions. This is just one of the **many** quirks about the language.

I personally prefer to use `AS` whenever I'm creating functions it as a matter of style, because it more clearly separates the signature of the function from the body, and it makes the syntax more consistent with the syntax for creating stored procedures (even if the language doesn't require it).

Comment: [] means optional? and where it writes or how could I learned that it means optional if you were not here? thanks

Comment: @osman See my updated answer for a link regarding to how read this syntax diagram.

Comment: Yes indeed... :^) *consistency* is not a term I'd apply to the designers of the Transact-SQL grammar.

Comment: @osman: see the document [*Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx) for how to read the documentation.